# Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Message: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Currently I'm working on a small website application (ASP.NET C# and JavaScript). All was working perfectly until this server error. Now I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (32bit OS). When I'm running the project in VS 2012, I'm getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Message: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'ID'

I'm also using the AJAX Control Toolkit for calendar pop up:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" enablepagemethods="True" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="Bookeddate"   />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="functiondate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Could you please post your markup code with the text boxes used by these extenders?

Comment: @SachinMhetre Can you please explain why you rejected a far more [substantial edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10555201) for that one word change?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" />
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Bookeddate" runat="server" />
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="Bookeddate" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply ,

I added this below code in the "Masterpage.Master" of the aspx project

"

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" 
ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

"

inside the "

```
    <body>
         <form id="form1" runat="server">
         </form>
    </body>
```

"